# Server Location Date Format is being ignored when sending date to Http GEt parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, datetime, localization

My Station is configured to EU Location format for date: dd/mm/yyyy
Everything is working fine expect when I send a date as a parameter via HTTP get:

```
http://localhost:6105/assignment?date=07/02/2011
```

This call is received by this code:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)
{
}
```

as date = 2.7.2011

any other date reference in the site is working OK and as expected (dd/mm/yyyy).

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you and found the solution at this site: [Localization of dates in asp.net](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/localization-of-dates-in-asp-net-mvc/). The issue is that MVC does not support localization of DateTimes in GET-requests, only in POST-requests. This is by design!
The blog post mentions some javascript-hacks to avoid this issue but I'd change to use culture-invariant dates.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 2 years but I used this method :

I pass the parameter as a string and parse it to a DateTime in the backend code :

```
public ActionResult Index(string date = null)
{
    DatetTime realDate;
    DateTime.TryParse(date, out realDate)


}
```